# In Vue Route, the parent path component display with the child path component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have 2 components, `AboutView.vue` and `HomeView.vue`.

`AboutView.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
    <router-link to="/about/add">Add</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

`HomeView.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I click the 'Add' button, I will be redirected to `/about/add` where `/add` is config inside `index.js`

```
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: AboutView,
    children:[
      {
          path: 'add',
          name: 'Add',
          component: ()=> import ('../views/HomeView.vue'),
      },
    ]
  }
```

The path is working fine.

But the problem is when I click the 'Add' button, what I would expect is it brought me to the `HomeView.vue`, but instead, it showed the `HomeView.vue` below the Add button.
Here is the screen.
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX4IQ.png)
it seems like the `route-view` is a part of the template, but I want it to display the `HomeView.vue` instead of `AboutView + HomeView`.

I tried to use `<router-view name='name></router-view>`, which doesn't help much. I can write a js function to check the path and make the code above disappear, but I expect something more professional.

Comment: Maybe you should no need `router-view` in `AboutView.vue`, and move `HomeView`  to where the same level with `AboutView` in `index.js`. Because I think `AboutView` and `HomeView` are two different page.

Comment: just remove the router-view in AboutView.vue. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views router-view usually use to be display multi vue pages.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to understand from the below image-

[image]

> router-view is basically the view where the components are rendered.
> It’s like the main div that contains all the components, and it
> returns the component that matches the current route.

So, to fix this just remove the `router-view` from `AboutView.vue` component, so when you will redirect to `/home`, the component `HomeView.vue`, will render inside `App.vue's` `router-view`.